# Need to exclude all rows based on one where condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a database with three tables. One table is called `recipe` with these columns:

```
EntryDate, Recipename, IngredientName, IngredientQty, QtyMeasurement
```

There are only two recipes in the database at this time. The first recipe, called Kitchen Sink Cookies, has 17 ingredients and the second recipe, called No Bake Cookies II, has only 6 ingredients.

Recipe 1 (Kitchen Sink) uses eggs as an ingredient. I need to find all recipes that do not use eggs.

So far I can only get it to return either both recipes or nothing. I have googled for a few hours now but am unable to get a query to work.

This is the latest query I have tried and it returns nothing.

```
Use recipes;
Go

Select
    RecipeName
From
    recipe
Where
    RecipeName Not In
    (
        select
            RecipeName
        from
            recipe
        where
            IngredientName Not Like 'EGG%'
        Group By
            RecipeName
    );
Go
```

So what I need to happen is if a recipe has an ingredient that is egg I need to exclude the recipe name from the output.

Does anyone have any ideas, or links that I can view (That I haven't looked at yet), or code samples?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What are the other tables in the database? Please post their schema (table-design) and sample data. How does `Recipe` contain `IngredientName`? That doesn't make any sense if each `Recipe` row represents a single recipe as each recipe can only have a single ingredient.

Comment: That doesn't solve your problem, but could make your query far simpler by removing that whole `IN` operation from the outer `WHERE` operation and simply put `IngredientName Not Like 'EGG%'`. It would be equivalent to what you have.

Comment: No. Each row is one ingredient. So there can be any number of ingredients each its own row. Dai in the first paragraph I list all of the columns in the table...Sticky Bit when I do that it gives me either both recipes if I do a Distinct or 17 of Kitchen Sink and 6 of No Bake Cookies II...

Comment: @stickybit this would also filter out recipes containing an **egg plant**... **mbcharney** can you please provide some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get rid of the **NOT LIKE**...

```
    Use recipes;
    Go

    Select
        RecipeName
    From
        recipe
    Where
        RecipeName Not In
        (
            select
                RecipeName
            from
                recipe
            where
                IngredientName IN ('EGG','EGGS')
            Group By
                RecipeName
        );
    Go
```

Also, as mentioned in the comments I would recommend not to use the **LIKE** operator because you will get no results for recipes with **egg plants** f.e.

A better approach would be:

```
    WHERE IngredientName IN ('EGG','EGGS')
```

Answer (score 1):

is this helpful?

```
    SELECT * FROM recipe WHERE Recipename NOT IN
    (SELECT Recipename FROM recipe WHERE IngredientName LIKE 'EGG%')
```

OR

```
    SELECT r1.* from recipe r1
    LEFT JOIN recipe r2 on r1.Recipename = r2.Recipename AND r2.IngredientName LIKE 'EGG%'
    WHERE r2.Recipename is NULL
```